# Suggestion: The best way to send messages on Facebook without getting banned using python

Tags: python, facebook, automation, chatbot

I'm using a python script that monitors a website and sends me messages on Facebook if there is any specific updates.
I have tried a module which called 'fbchat', so simple and so easy, but the problem is that I'm using real Facebook accounts and somehow Facebook detected that it's a bot and banned that profile, even if I have made random pauses in my code.

I know that I can do make those notifications through emails, but for me Facebook messages are better... Any ideas about how can I make it possible (maybe through bots!!)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at which parameters(headers and payloads) the POST method takes(using network tools in google chrome for example), and try again with as many parameters as possible, while also using a session so cookies are enabled as well.

Different websites use different methods of detecting bots, and you'll just have to test and see what works.

P.S: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956652/7764138) for more info.

Comment: The Facebook profile that I have used worked for a long period than stopped, and like I have said I have made a random time pauses between the messages and also it connects only one time, so I think that Facebook will figure out this after all.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Accounts are not allowed on Facebook, and there is no (allowed) way to send messages between users. You can only send messages from Pages to Users, and only if the User started the conversation. You can find more information about that in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/